# i need to bring all products for this category and sub category to end level

Tags: php, database, function, mysqli

I need to bring all products for all categories and sub categories. How it works and what is wrong with this code?

This a function I need to correct and i will put it in pagination code and also jQuery code which filter the corresponding to price low and high newest oldest products

```
<?php
            function listproducts ($category_img=filter_var($_GET['category'],FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT)){
                global $conn;
                $sql_cat_name="select * from categories where cat_id='$category_img' or cat_id in (select cat_id from categories where cat_parent_id='$category_img')";
                $query_cat_name=mysqli_query($conn,$sql_cat_name);
                while($result_cat_name=mysqli_fetch_array($query_cat_name)){
                    $ref_id=$result_cat_name['cat_id'];
                    $show_all_pro="select * from products where product_category='$ref_id'";
                    $query_show_all=mysqli_query($conn,$show_all_pro);
                    while($result_show_all=mysqli_fetch_array($query_show_all)){
                ?>
                <!-- 12 product.-->
            <div class="category-product-inner wow fadeInUp">
              <div class="products">
                <div class="product-list product">
                  <div class="row product-list-row">
                    <div class="col col-sm-4 col-lg-4">
                      <div class="product-image">
                        <div class="image"> <img src="assets/images/products/p3.jpg" alt=""> </div>
                      </div>
                      <!-- /.product-image --> 
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.col -->
                    <div class="col col-sm-8 col-lg-8">
                      <div class="product-info">
                        <h3 class="name"><a href="detail.html">Floral Print Buttoned</a></h3>
                        <div class="rating rateit-small"></div>
                        <div class="product-price"> <span class="price"> $450.99 </span> <span class="price-before-discount">$ 800</span> </div>
                        <!-- /.product-price -->
                        <div class="description m-t-10">Suspendisse posuere arcu diam, id accumsan eros pharetra ac. Nulla enim risus, facilisis bibendum gravida eget, lacinia id purus. Suspendisse posuere arcu diam, id accumsan eros pharetra ac. Nulla enim risus, facilisis bibendum gravida eget.</div>
                        <div class="cart clearfix animate-effect">
                          <div class="action">
                            <ul class="list-unstyled">
                              <li class="add-cart-button btn-group">
                                <button class="btn btn-primary icon" data-toggle="dropdown" type="button"> <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> </button>
                                <button class="btn btn-primary cart-btn" type="button">Add to cart</button>
                              </li>
                              <li class="lnk wishlist"> <a class="add-to-cart" href="detail.html" title="Wishlist"> <i class="icon fa fa-heart"></i> </a> </li>
                              <li class="lnk"> <a class="add-to-cart" href="detail.html" title="Compare"> <i class="fa fa-signal"></i> </a> </li>
                            </ul>
                          </div>
                          <!-- /.action --> 
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.cart --> 
                      </div>
                      <!-- /.product-info --> 
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.col --> 
                  </div>
                  <!-- /.product-list-row -->
                  <div class="tag new"><span>new</span></div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.product-list --> 
              </div>
              <!-- /.products --> 
            </div>
            <!-- /.category-product-inner -->
                <?
                    }
                    listproducts ($result_cat_name['cat_id']);
                }
            }
            echo listproducts();
        ?>
```

This is my tables need to bring from them

Categories
[image]

Products
[image]

Comment: nothing happen to the code

Comment: another thing i made it with laravel i see there is recursive loop to make this can you tell my how to do this function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Displaying html code that way only works outside functions.
If you really want to do it that way, you need to put your html code into a `echo`, that way :

```
<?php
function listproducts ($category_img=filter_var($_GET['category'],FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT)){
    global $conn;
    $sql_cat_name="select * from categories where cat_id='$category_img' or cat_id in (select cat_id from categories where cat_parent_id='$category_img')";
    $query_cat_name=mysqli_query($conn,$sql_cat_name);
    while($result_cat_name=mysqli_fetch_array($query_cat_name)){
        $ref_id=$result_cat_name['cat_id'];
        $show_all_pro="select * from products where product_category='$ref_id'";
        $query_show_all=mysqli_query($conn,$show_all_pro);
        while($result_show_all=mysqli_fetch_array($query_show_all)){
            echo '
            <!-- 12 product.-->
            <div class="category-product-inner wow fadeInUp">
                <div class="products">
                    <div class="product-list product">
                        <div class="row product-list-row">
                            <div class="col col-sm-4 col-lg-4">
                                <div class="product-image">
                                    <div class="image"> <img src="assets/images/products/p3.jpg" alt=""> </div>
                                </div>
                                <!-- /.product-image -->
                            </div>
                            <!-- /.col -->
                            <div class="col col-sm-8 col-lg-8">
                                <div class="product-info">
                                    <h3 class="name"><a href="detail.html">Floral Print Buttoned</a></h3>
                                    <div class="rating rateit-small"></div>
                                    <div class="product-price"> <span class="price"> $450.99 </span> <span class="price-before-discount">$ 800</span> </div>
                                    <!-- /.product-price -->
                                    <div class="description m-t-10">Suspendisse posuere arcu diam, id accumsan eros pharetra ac. Nulla enim risus, facilisis bibendum gravida eget, lacinia id purus. Suspendisse posuere arcu diam, id accumsan eros pharetra ac. Nulla enim risus, facilisis bibendum gravida eget.</div>
                                    <div class="cart clearfix animate-effect">
                                        <div class="action">
                                            <ul class="list-unstyled">
                                                <li class="add-cart-button btn-group">
                                                    <button class="btn btn-primary icon" data-toggle="dropdown" type="button"> <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> </button>
                                                    <button class="btn btn-primary cart-btn" type="button">Add to cart</button>
                                                </li>
                                                <li class="lnk wishlist"> <a class="add-to-cart" href="detail.html" title="Wishlist"> <i class="icon fa fa-heart"></i> </a> </li>
                                                <li class="lnk"> <a class="add-to-cart" href="detail.html" title="Compare"> <i class="fa fa-signal"></i> </a> </li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </div>
                                        <!-- /.action -->
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- /.cart -->
                                </div>
                                <!-- /.product-info -->
                            </div>
                            <!-- /.col -->
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.product-list-row -->
                        <div class="tag new"><span>new</span></div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.product-list -->
                </div>
                <!-- /.products -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.category-product-inner -->
            ';
        }
        listproducts ($result_cat_name['cat_id']);
    }
}
echo listproducts();
?>
```